# Set variable returning Nothing in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Update:** Issue Resolved

Solution 1:
Thanks to @Tim Williams  for this solution. There was some issue with cell/ColB formatting. After resetting the format to "General" it work.

Solution 2:
Thanks to @Chris neilsen for second solution.
Change the LookIn:=xlValues to LookIn:=xlFormulas

I'm unable to fetch the data from sheet4 when i search for PhoneNumber.

The excel contain 4 work sheets.

Sheet1 is the main sheet.
Sheet4 is the data storing sheet.

In sheet4,  It have 4 columns -

```
A        B           C            D 
Name     PhoneNo     Address1     Address 2
```

The value in Sheet4

```txt
Column A        Column B 
CustomerName    Phone Number 
CustomerName1   1001001001 
CustomerName2   1001001002  
CustomerName3   1001001003 
CustomerName4   1001001004  
CustomerName5   1001001005
```

Column Value in Sheet4. Refer the below image

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7hNe.png

I set the phonenumber as following format in sheet4 & Sheet1 via cell formatting --> Number

Set findPhoneNo  returning Nothing.
Refer the below Image:
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q1Wg.png

```
    Option Explicit

Sub SearchCustomerByPhoneNumber()

Dim findPhoneNo As Range
Dim CustRowPhNo As String
Dim OutPut As MsoAlertButtonType
Dim phNo As Long

'phNo = Format(Sheet1.Range("N14").Value, "##########")



'Set findPhoneNo = Sheet4.Range("B:B").Find(Sheet1.Range("N14").Value, , LookIn:=xlValues)
Set findPhoneNo = Sheet4.Range("B:B").Find(Sheet1.Range("N14").Value, _
After:=Sheet4.Range("B1"), _
LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, _
MatchByte:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)

If Not findPhoneNo Is Nothing Then

    CustRowPhNo = Range(findPhoneNo.Address).Row
    Range("L14").Value = CustRowPhNo
       
    Range("C9").Value = Sheet4.Range("A" & CustRowPhNo).Value 'A - Customer Name
    Range("C12").Value = Sheet4.Range("B" & CustRowPhNo).Value 'B - Phone Number

        
 Else
       
   
End If
End Sub
```

**I have uploaded the sample workbook to MediaFire.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/yq43lx8x4ba2buo/Sample_V1.xlsm/file

Comment: tl;dr So what is your actual question or issue?

Comment: Needs examples of the actual values being searched for, and the values in ColB on sheet 4.  We need to be able to reproduce your problem in order to help you fix it...

Comment: The value i'm searching "1001001004"

Comment: Using Find() to search for `1001001004` in a column which contains that value works fine for me in testing.

Comment: I'm not sure where i'm doing wrong. I used the simple search   Set findPhoneNo = Sheet4.Range("B:B").Find(Sheet1.Range("N14").Value)

Comment: When using `Find`, it's best to always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters. See the "Remarks" section in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: Even after specifying,  its not finding the value from the sheet4.                                                              Set findPhoneNo = Sheet4.Range("B:B").Find(Sheet1.Range("N14").Value, _
After:=Sheet4.Range("B1"), _
LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, _
MatchByte:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)

Comment: Chris,  i did check, both are number fields. Both are set with same formatting,  Format cells --> Number (with zero decimals)

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I have 'Data validation" enabled for Sheet4's Column B as follows:
"Whole number between '1000000000' & "9999999999"

I also checked if each cell is numeric or not in Excel via formula = IsNumeric().

Comment: Your file link is broken

Comment: @TimWilliams Here is updated link   https://www.mediafire.com/file/yq43lx8x4ba2buo/Sample_V1.xlsm/file

Comment: @viku I just had a look at your file.  You have all the parameters to the Find commented out.  Fix that and I think you will find it works

Comment: It does not work is ColB on Customers is formatted as "Number"   It will work if you change the format to "General"  EDIT - now it works with either...   There was some weird formatting thing there which seems like it has cleared out...

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams   It did fix the issue.  
I changed the ColB & Search-value field format to 'General", it worked fine.

Again, i changed the 'General' format to 'Number' format, it worked too. Setting to Phone number format, somehow messing up.    Thank you All for helping out. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you change `LookIn:=xlValues` to `LookIn:=xlFormulas` it will work with Phone Number format

Comment: Thank you @chrisneilsen  It worked as well. Much appreciated.     I never thought formatting is considered as "Formulas"  , that's why i did not change that PARMs.